# React - how to make only one increment function setState multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I simplify this code so that I don't need to a have a separate Increment function for each quantity variable?

Is there a way to pass parameters? I also have to add decrement functions for each quantity variable.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    // Define data above render()
    constructor(){
      super(); 

      this.state = {
        quantity1: 0,
        quantity2: 0,
        quantity3: 0,
        quantity4: 0,
        quantity5: 0,
        quantity6: 0,
      }      

    }

    onChange (event) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
    }

    IncrementItem = () => {
      this.setState({ quantity1: this.state.quantity1 + 1 });
    }

    IncrementItem2 = () => {
      this.setState({ quantity2: this.state.quantity2 + 1 });
    }

    IncrementItem3 = () => {
      this.setState({ quantity3: this.state.quantity3 + 1 });
    }

    render() {
        // Show data in React expression.
        return( 
            <div>
                Server name: <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)} /><br></br>
                <br></br>

                 Server: {this.state.value}<br></br>
                 <button onClick={this.Reset}>Reset</button>

                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Item1</td>
                      <td>0.99</td>
                      <td><button onClick={this.IncrementItem}>+</button> <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem}>-</button></td>
                      <td>{this.state.quantity1}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Item2</td>
                      <td>0.99</td>
                      <td><button onClick={this.IncrementItem2}>+</button> <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem2}>-</button></td>
                      <td>{this.state.quantity2}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                  </table>
            </div>
        );     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method as you've used for the `onChange` function, which is to determine the property name based on which element called the function.

Something like this:

```
increment = (propName) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({[propName]: ++prevState[propName]}))
}
```

and to call it with the appropriate parameter, you can use `bind`:

```
<button onClick={this.increment.bind(this, 'quantity1')}>+</button>
```

Or something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.increment('quantity1')}>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define a single and generalised increment function like so, that takes the key of the state value that you want to increment:

```
IncrementItemByKey = (key) => {

  const lastValue = this.state[ key ];

  this.setState({ [ key ]: lastValue + 1 });
}

DecreaseItemByKey = (key) => {

  const lastValue = this.state[ key ];

  this.setState({ [ key ]: lastValue - 1 });
}
```

And then use it like so, passing in the "quantity" key that you want to increment and decrement per button:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>0.99</td>
    <td>
    <button onClick={ () => this.IncrementItemByKey('quantity1') }>+</button>
    <button onClick={ () => this.DecreaseItemByKey('quantity1') }>-</button></td>
    <td>{this.state.quantity1}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>0.99</td>
    <td>
    <button onClick={ () => this.IncrementItemByKey('quantity2') }>+</button> 
    <button onClick={ () => this.DecreaseItemByKey('quantity2') }>-</button></td>
    <td>{this.state.quantity2}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `name` in your buttons, you can retrieve it from the click event.

```
IncrementItem = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target;

    this.setState(prevState => ({ [name]: prevState[name] + 1 }));
}

DecreaseItem = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target;

    this.setState(prevState => ({ [name]: prevState[name] - 1 }));
}
```

Set `name` in your buttons to be exactly the same as in your state:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>0.99</td>
    <td><button onClick={this.IncrementItem} name='quantity1'>+</button> <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem} name='quantity1'>-</button></td>
    <td>{this.state.quantity1}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>0.99</td>
    <td><button onClick={this.IncrementItem} name='quantity2'>+</button> <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem} name='quantity2'>-</button></td>
    <td>{this.state.quantity2}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```